# C# Code to read multiple files(26) from location and load to sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

I am novice in C# coding. I have 26 files that get loaded to a shared location. Every night the files get deleted. I needed to create ssis package to load the 26 files to SQL Server. The code I have does not load all the 26 files. It just reads 2 files 26 times and exits. Unsure how to debug the code. The code basically reads all the 26 files, loads them one after the other. It should not read the same file again. So I added that condition in as well.

EDIT:
Theres a foreach loop container which has one script task- that contains the below code. And from the script task there are 26 branches for data flow tasks. The script task provides the filename to data flow task for it to run the specific file.

```
public void Main()
{
    string sourceFolder = Dts.Variables["User::SourceFolder"].Value.ToString();
    string fileExtension = Dts.Variables["User::FileExtension"].Value.ToString();
    string lastProcessedFile = Dts.Variables["User::LastProcessedFile"].Value.ToString();

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder, "*" + fileExtension);

    // Dictionary to store the file name and its corresponding timestamp
    Dictionary<string, DateTime> fileTimestamps = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
        string fileTimestamp = fileName.Substring((fileName.Length - 14), 14); // Assuming the timestamp has a length of 14 characters

        DateTime timestamp;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(fileTimestamp, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out timestamp))
        {
            fileTimestamps.Add(file, timestamp);
        }
    }

    // Get the latest file based on the timestamp
    var sortedFiles = fileTimestamps.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value);
    
    string latestFile = sortedFiles.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Key != lastProcessedFile).Key;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(latestFile))
    {
        // Set the latest file path to a package variable
        Dts.Variables["User::LatestFile"].Value = latestFile;
        Dts.Variables["User::LastProcessedFile"].Value = latestFile;

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
    else
    {
        // No new files found in the folder
        MessageBox.Show("No new files found in the folder.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
    }
}
```

I tried changing the if/else conditions. I am expecting the code to read the other 24 files. Could anyone please direct me to where the issue is ?

Comment: I don't see anything reading anything here? You just get some files.

Comment: Script tasks aren't used to load files. Use a ForEach loop container that works on a folder's contents and in that container use a Data flow that imports each file

Comment: Check for example [Loop through Flat Files in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/)

Comment: The script task provided computes values for the user variables `LatestFile` and `LastProcessedFile` Does that work correctly? What does your Foreach Enumerator enumerate and assuming it's the file system, to what variable are you assigning values and what is the selector in the enumerator (file name, full file name, some other option I don't remember)